# C# RESTful WebApi post data in Arabic language in json but receiving?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, arabic, restful-url

In C# WebApi, while trying to receive data in Arabic language in json format (sent via **Soap UI**) I receive "???" instead of the actual Arabic text.

**URL:**

http://localhost:4321/receive/message

**Json format (Request):**

```
{
   "message_no";"123",
   "user_id":"a123",
   "text":"أهلا بك",
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class MessageBody
{
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "message_no")]
        public string MessageNo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
        public int Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Content received:**

MessageNo: 123

UserId: a123

Text: ??????

Comment: Do you using 'UTF-8' encoder on both Server side and Client side?

Comment: Right now I am not using any encoder, can you provide sample code on how to use 'UTF-8' encode on server side?

Comment: What is that you see when you hit this url from chrome browser (assuming this is a GET request)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the bytes which were convereted from UTF-8 at server side, any client side code can also then using various String encoding formats to display the test.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your string to this method.This will return the required text.

```
public string DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters(string value)
            {
                return Regex.Replace(
                    value,
                    @"\\u(?<Value>[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})",
                    m =>
                    {
                        return ((char)int.Parse(m.Groups["Value"].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString();
                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Client side:**

*Just for post data using HTML page.*

Besides UTF-8 format to save the file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

**For server side:**

Add below into `web.config` and make it in `<system.web>` element.

```
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you declared Text as int. It should be string

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
public int Text { get; set; }